# importing my own library: Uncaught ReferenceError: mylib is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to learn how to write a small library to import in my projects. I'm using Webpack for bundling.

Everything is fine until I try to create a new instance of my class:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mylib is not defined

My library:

```
class mylib {
  constructor(input) {
    this.sayHello(input)
  }

  sayHello(name) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name);
  }
}
```

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: './mylib.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"]
  }
};
```

Index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/mylib.js"></script>
<script>
  (function() {
    var test = new mylib('myname');
  })();
</script>
<body>
<pre>...</pre>
</body>
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of to be able to use the library in other places, but nothing is helping...

Where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When using webpack, you have to use import/export to use a class from a library. A class will not be accessible globally (at least not by default).

If you want to use this class globally anyhow, you should add something like this to your webpack config: (as seen on https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)

```
output: {
    // export itself to a global var
    libraryTarget: "var",
    // name of the global var: "mylib"
    library: "mylib"
}
```

However, I would recommend importing the lib in another file or project where you use webpack instead of writing it in the HTML-file itself.

Either way, don't forget to add export default to your index.js file:

```
export default mylib;
```